# java howto convert comma and slash string to array

Tags: java

I have the following string:

```
str = /data/media/file1.txt,/data/media/file2.jpg,/data/media/file3.jpg
```

I want to have array with file names.
I tried all kind of splits. it didn't work.
please help :)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Split on comma, iterate over results, then split each result on slash, get last element. Or don't split on slash. Use path to create `File` which will give you access to its `getName` method.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: It's better you use a colon or a character which is not allowed in the file names...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` method of a String I guess, like this:

```
String[] mySplittedString = str.split(","); //The comma is the split point of each part of the string
```

Which should result:

```
mySplittedString[0] ==> "/data/media/file1.txt"
mySplittedString[1] ==> "/data/media/file2.jpg"
mySplittedString[2] ==> "/data/media/file3.jpg"
```

Hope it helps!

---

**NOTE:** *Be careful with file names that contain comma themselves, which will be splitted at the wrong place.*

---

**Source: http://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-split**

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "/data/media/file1.txt,/data/media/file2.jpg,/data/media/file3.jpg";

String files[] = str.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i<files.length; i++) {
    files[i] = files[i].substring(files[i].lastIndexOf("/")+1, files[i].length());
}
```